# multi-tasking with freertos in STM32F4x not working

Tags: eclipse, freertos, stm32f4

we have used FreeRTOS API to create task and scheduler is run still only one task is running and context switching is not happening between multiple tasks created using FreeRTOS APIs. While running the following code it is always running into task3 (for debugging using Eclipse-GDB).

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get up and running with FreeRTOS as quickly as possible is to start with a [known good pre-configured project](http://www.freertos.org/a00090.html#ST) that is provided for you, then once that is running, [adapt it](http://www.freertos.org/porting-a-freertos-demo-to-different-hardware.html) by stripping out the example code and adding in your application code.  Alternatively have the STM32Cube software provided by ST create the project for you.  If you then have problems you can check out the "[my application does not run, what could be wrong](http://www.freertos.org/FAQHelp.html)?" page of the FAQ.